# How to hook on @Input property change?

Tags: angular

I have a data binding from parent to child component and the childs template renders the data.

How can I act, in the child, on the event of the data being changed so I can do stuff with it before I render it?

Comment: If you only want to change the visual appearance of the data, you could use pipes inside the template. Otherwise the solution of KId seems good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using

```
@Input() myInputVariable;
```

You can intercept the input property changes with a setter, you can read more [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter)

```
@Input()
set myInputVariable(value: boolean) {
    // Do Something here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked - will accept when the timer allows.

Where can I find this in the documentation, btw?